# DS1220 vs X2816A

Tags: ram

I have a legacy device from 1996 that uses a Dallas DS1220 NV RAM. The battery is shot and the device won't even boot. But if I swap in 6116 RAM chip, it comes up and works but of course won't save any of the user settings upon power off. I tried putting in a Xicor X2816A but that did not work at all.

I am probably not understanding something about these old EE RAM chips. Can someone enlighten me as to how the X2816 works as compared to a standard 6116 or a 2716 in the case of a UV ROM?

Answer (score 1):

The Xicor chip is an EEPROM, not a RAM. It has a write cycle time of 10 **milli**seconds, which means it isn't just a drop-in replacement for battery-backed SRAM, which is what the Dallas chip is. The 6116 is the same kind of SRAM as the DS1220, but without the battery.

You might come close to the functionality of the DS1220 by adding a 3 V coin cell and a dual Schottky diode to the 6116 Vcc pin. You will also need a CMOS gate, powered by the coin cell, that holds CS- high whenever primary power is low. There will be some small chance of data corruption if writes are occurring when the primary power cuts off.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I overlooked that write timing spec. The X2816 access time is specified as 450ns, same as the old NVRAM chip. But I guess they mean read access, not write.

Comment: At a pinch you can carve off the top of the ds1220 to expose the battery then remove it and solder in another button cell. It’s a bit brutal. Nevertheless you can still get the DS1220 or equivalent either as the complete module or as a smart socket.

Comment: A drop-in replacement might be available in the form of an FRAM chip. FRAM is nonvolatile even without a battery, like EEPROM, but it has read and write times similar to SRAM, so you can get it in the same pinout as common SRAM chips.

Comment: Kartman, I do see plenty of DS1220 available from surplus shops. But my concern is they are 20-30 years old as well. I know the battery is not connected until the first application of VCC, but I still don't trust a 20+ year old NOS battery?